# OSC Htaccess Catch All Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a subdomain called ice.domain.com and i have a new domain called icedomain.com
I want to catch all url redirect to icedomain but i have some redirect setup already.
I tried putting 301 redirect but the rewrite rule will stop working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
redirect 301 / http://icedomain.com/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=28$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.icedomain.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=58B-9x12-10- [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=29$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.icedomain.com/Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=30$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.icedomain.com/Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=31$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.icedomain.com/Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect everything that was not redirected by your other rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.icedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.icedomain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=28$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ /ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=58B-9x12-10- [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=29$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ /Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=30$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ /Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=31$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ /Danfoss-s/1679.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ...and you expect, that I know what you've changed then?!

Comment: actually I didn't change anything, what i mean is, it is not working as expected . it redirects when you type ice.domain.com to icedomain.com but when you type ice.domain.com/product.php?123&456 , it is not not redirecting to icedomain.com, the purpose is to catch all url and redirect them to icedomain.com. Thanks